# No output to console in Miscrosoft Expression Blend?

Tags: xaml, console, blend

I'm afraid this is a dumb question, but I'm tired of searching for a solution.
I can't send anything to the output window (Results -> Output) in Expression Blend.
I tried with 'Console.WriteLine', 'Console.Out.WriteLine' and 'Debug.WriteLine' but I can´t see anything.

Thanks for your help

Comment: There _may_ be a way to do this (and I'd be curious to see if it's possible), but Expression Blend is really meant to be used by designers, not programmers. I usually have the same project open in both VS and Blend and use Blend for the visuals, then compile and run in VS.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("this should work");
```